# Timeout when installing the Facebook nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

> PM> Install-Package Facebook
>   Install-Package : The operation has timed out
>   At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Facebook
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Where can I download the Package online and then how can I integrate it with VS 2012?

Comment: Works for me.  Temporary problem with the server?  Try again now.

Comment: Does it work with other packages? Some enterprise proxies block all URLs that contain things like "facebook" or "youtube"...

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was fixed by going to Tools > Extensions and Updates... and installing the latest NuGet Package Manager.

[image]